# Switch current window to previous current window

Tags: vim

I frequently have two Vim windows open (with a `:vsplit`). Is there a command, or sequence of commands, that will switch my current (selected) window to the window that was previously current.

So if I have two windows displays, with a vertical split separating them (with the left window being the current window), and I execute the key combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> (move the current window to the right window), is there a key combo I can type that will switch me back to the left window, which if I type again will switch me back to the right window?

Comment: Just in case anybody is interested, I use :b# to switch to the previous buffer.

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> (<kbd>P</kbd> stands for previous) should do the trick. I suggest you do `:help window` as well, you might learn interesting stuff.

Comment: @Elephant can you accept the answer if you're happy with it ?

Answer (score 4):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> <kbd>W</kbd> (actually mb14's answer is better since this will work ok if only 2 windows are open)

Comment: This is actually an incorrect answer, and happens to work with 2 windows only because... well.. with two windows you don't have much choice.

Comment: @NathanFellman: therfore it's not incorrect with 2 windows. Rethink your downvote. Chances are you're more likely to use ctrl-w-w anyway if you have 2 windows open since it's quicker.